# Unable to set up a server due to an error in socket.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import socket

print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()));
TCP_IP = "192.168.56.1";
TCP_PORT = 8080;
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT));


conn, addr = s.accept();
print('Connection address:' + addr);
while 1:
    print("Started: ");
    data = conn.recv(20);
    if not data: break
    print ("received data:", data);
    conn.send(data);
conn.close();
```

Consider the following code, I'm trying to set up a WIFi TCP server on Python. For some reason however when run the output I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Yoga/PycharmProjects/untitled/exec", line 10, in <module>
    conn, addr = s.accept();
  File "C:\Users\Yoga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 212, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

Apparently there's some kind of error in `socket.py`. Suggestions how to fix are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after `s.bind()` and before `s.accept()` you have to call `s.listen()` once.

check out the [Echo example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example) in the official docs.